# Is it safe to move Windows\Installer to another drive?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, ntfs

This folder is way too big to have on an SSD but I've heard deleting it can cause problems when uninstalling programs, is it safe to move it to another drive using NTFS link junction things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've also linked the folder from my SSD to my HDD and I have no issues so far. So I would say it is safe.

I've used this tool:

http://bitsum.com/junctionmaster.php

Select the Installer folder, make a rightclick and select "Move and Link folder to":

[image]

Select a folder on the HDD and click "Move and Link":

[image]